# how is adoption of the activity stream standard (activitystrea.ms)

Tags: android-activity, stream, feed

I am new to look at the activity standard. When i search on google, I quickly find there has the http://activitystrea.ms/ and in the first page, it said: The Activity Streams format has already been adopted by BBC, Gnip, Google Buzz Gowalla, IBM, MySpace, Opera, Socialcast, Superfeedr, TypePad, Windows Live, YIID, and many others.

I am not quite sure if it is still live and any other activity standard that much more popular in industry?

macf

Answer (score 6):

Over at Fashiolista we've opensourced our approach to building feed systems.
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Feedly
We also use the activity stream standard and we're quite happy with it. As far as I know there are no other standards which have become mainstream. I do think that most companies slightly deviate from the standards.

In addition have a look at this high scalability post were we explain some of the design decisions involved:
http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/10/28/design-decisions-for-scaling-your-high-traffic-feeds.html

[This tutorial](http://www.mellowmorning.com/2013/10/18/scalable-pinterest-tutorial-feedly-redis/) will help you setup a system like Pinterest's feed using Redis. It's quite easy to get started with.

To learn more about feed design I highly recommend reading some of the articles which we based Feedly on:

- [Yahoo Research Paper](http://research.yahoo.com/files/sigmod278-silberstein.pdf)
- [Twitter 2013 Redis based](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/8/the-architecture-twitter-uses-to-deal-with-150m-active-users.html), with fallback
- [Cassandra at Instagram](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/instagram-making-the-switch-to-cassandra-from-redis-75-instasavings)
- [Etsy feed scaling](http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture/)
- [Facebook history](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Facebook-Software-Stack)
- [Django project](http://justquick.github.com/django-activity-stream/), with good naming conventions. (But database only)
- http://activitystrea.ms/specs/atom/1.0/ (actor, verb, object, target)
- [Quora post on best practises](http://www.quora.com/What-are-best-practices-for-building-something-like-a-News-Feed?q=news%20feeds)
- [Quora scaling a social network feed](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-scaling-issues-to-keep-in-mind-while-developing-a-social-network-feed)
- [Redis ruby example](http://web.archive.org/web/20130525202810/http://blog.waxman.me/how-to-build-a-fast-news-feed-in-redis)
- [FriendFeed approach](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql)
- [Thoonk setup](http://blog.thoonk.com/)
- [Twitter's Approach](http://www.slideshare.net/nkallen/q-con-3770885)